# Displaying Default Resources on SP13 Group Calendar

Tags: calendar, resources

I'm working with a group calendar on SP13, trying to show default resources on a standard, monthly calendar view.

I've followed the directions at [this site](http://zepeda-mcmillan.blogspot.com/2011/03/displaying-default-resources-on-group.html) but for some reason IE is throwing an error on `SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarSelector.instance().getSelector(1, $(el).attr('ctxid'))` because the `ctxid` attribute has not been defined yet.

After looking into things, it appears that the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` for `sp.ribbon.js` is not actually waiting until `sp.ribbon.j`s is finished loading.

While debugging, the `getSelector` call does eventually resolve to an object, but after the rest of my script runs, which makes it too late. Is there a better way to delay my script until `sp.ribbon.js` loads, or whatever it is that assigns the `ctxid`?

Answer (score 0):

So... answered my own question.

I changed the script slightly to call setTimeout for 1 second to delay the script just long enough for sp.ribbon.js to finish loading.